# How can i persist redux values whenever going to third party website(like amazon)

Tags: reactjs, redux

1. I searched the desired products & Displayed the all the products in product search page.
2. Filtered the products by producttype and price from the respective dropdowns
3. I selected one of the product from the  filtered product results and it is redirecting to amazon(third party website).
4. When going back to search page ,it clears all the filtered values(like product type, price values  stored in redux).
5. How can I persist the redux values whenever going to the third party website(like amazon)

When I came back to my website, the redux values(filtered values) should be available to show the filtered products page.How can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, redux is a "state" of application. So it is relative to the application and I don't think there is "Persistent redux". However, we can rebuild the state using several approaches as follow:

1. Store some queries or strings to the browser system. Can be localStorage, cookies etc. So, should be there is a mechanism when to write, read and delete the queries or strings. You need to rebuild the state of redux reducer when a page/router should read the queries/string value
2. Store your last redux reducer value to browser system too, and just easily apply to your reducer value
3. If your Amazon page support things like "URL referrer", you can put React router parameter value to build redux reducer state when you back to your React page.

So far those 3 things above I can think of :).

**UPDATE====**

I found an article which mentions several ways to achieve "Presistent Redux" by using additional library, you may want to check this: https://medium.com/async-la/redux-persist-your-state-7ad346c4dd07